# How can i recognise 2 lines License Plate with Tesseract OCR

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have tried recognizing car license plate with OCR with one line plate and the results is decent. I tried recognizing on two lines plate but it just gives me wrong results output. It either detect 1 line below or 1 line above or print out random values. What do i need to do to ensure detect and recognize two line plate? Please help out. Thank you.

Comment: Can you split those 2 lines into separate images & run OCR on each of them?

Comment: @DmitriiZ, I am able to save the images of the full plate. As for how to split the 2 lines, Can you please provide me more information on how i can do that? Thank you.